# R and double brackets for nested lists

Tags: r, list, nested, brackets

There are MANY posts about indexing lists, but I still can't quite get my head around indexing methods for named and unnamed nested lists. Here's my example

```
person <- list("name"="John","age"=19,"speaks"=c("English","French")) 
Johns_brother <- list("name"="Sam","age"=20,"speaks"=c("English","Spanish"))
Johns_sister <- list("name"="Minerva","age"=17,"speaks"=c("English","Italian"))
Johns_sister <- list("name"="Minerva","age"=17,"speaks"=c("English","Italian"))
Johns_other_sister <- list("name"="Casandra","age"=23,"speaks"=c("English","Greek"))
person <- list("name"="John","age"=19,"speaks"=c("English","French"),"siblings"=list(Johns_brother,Johns_sister,Johns_other_sister))
```

Both of these indexing methods return lists

```
class(person$siblings[1])
class(person$siblings[[1]])
```

But only the second allows me to select named elements

```
person$siblings[1]$name
person$siblings[[1]]$name
```

Now I've seen posts that insist (all caps in the original) "A DOUBLE BRACKET WILL NEVER RETURN A LIST. RATHER A DOUBLE BRACKET WILL RETURN ONLY A SINGLE ELEMENT FROM THE LIST" But that's obviously not true since both indexing methods return lists. But the two forms of brackets are returning DIFFERENT lists, right? What is the underlying logic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it.  The `[[` notation indexes the list element.  But what if that element itself is a list?

```
list(a = list(b = 1))[[1]]
# $b
# [1] 1
```

In the above example, the return value is still a list because `a` is a list.  The value returned depends on the value being indexed. The statement *A DOUBLE BRACKET WILL NEVER RETURN A LIST* is simply not true.

Help on this can be found in `help(Extract)` -

> Indexing by `[` is similar to atomic vectors and **selects a list** of the specified element(s).
>
> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list.

It also helps to know the difference between atomic and recursive (list-like) vectors.

Comment: Is there a blank top level to the list `person$siblings[1]` so that `person$siblings[1]$name` is NULL but `person$siblings[[1]]$name` is the named list? The simple command `person$siblings[1]` shows that I need double brackets to get to `$name` . . . so I get this practically but not conceptually . .  thanks

Comment: `person$siblings[1]` is a list of 3 unnamed elements.  To get to the names you need to use `person$siblings[[1]]`.  There is a major difference between `[` and `[[` explained in `help(Extract)`

Comment: This is actually starting to make sense by noting that `class(person[1])` is also a list . . . not a simple character element or vector! Thanks